# Firefox placement of toolbars

Tags: firefox

Like many others I sit in front of a widescreen monitor.

That means my screen is much wider than high ... nevertheless, Firefox (like many other software titles), stacks the UI vertically, instead  of using the real estate to the left or right.

[image]

Do you know of a way to place the menu (icons etc.) or status bar to the left and/or right side of the application window? 
e.g:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

For the tabs, you can use the [Tree Style Tabs extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/tree-style-tab/) to get them on the left.

As far as I know the status bar does not exist anymore, it has been replaced by the add-on bar, and can be hidden ([explanation](http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/what-happened-status-bar)).

This does not fully answer the question, but it's the best I have.

Comment: +1 .. every little bit helps! **Thanks!** I'll have to bring in the extension from home .. our company doesn't allow me to install them directly .. (mandatory proxy and censoring modules)

Answer (score 1):

The extension mentioned by @pataluc ([Tree Style Tabs](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/tree-style-tab/)) surely provides a good start.

Note that you can also hide your menu bar by right clicking free space in your tab bar and unchecking `Menu Bar` to get the small Firefox menu in the title bar. If you need quick access to your menu bar simply press <kbd>Alt</kbd>.

If *Full Screen* mode (<kbd>F11</kbd> or Firefox menu → Full Screen) is no option, you may also want to take a look at the following extensions to reclaim some space:

- [All-in-One-Sidebar](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/all-in-one-sidebar/): opens Bookmarks, History, Downloads, Add-ons, Page Info, and Error Console in the sidebar
- [Less Chrome HD](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/prospector-lessChrome-HD/): hides toolbars like the location bar navigation until you point at the tabs
- [Omnibar](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/omnibar/): Integrates location bar and search bar into one while still showing search and url suggestions
- [Vertical Toolbar](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/vertical-toolbar/): adds a vertical toolbar at the edge of the window
- [Addons in Urlbar](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/addons-in-urlbar/): puts all of your addon bar's icons in the urlbar and hides the add-on bar
- [A Better Firefox Add-on Bar](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/a-better-firefox-add-on-bar/): makes the addon bar look much cleaner and more convenient and auto-hides it. Hover over the bottom right corner to see it again.

**Please note that there is no particular order to the extensions listed above and that I don't know how compatible all of these extensions are!**